# How can I calculate relation between rss and vsz in ps command output bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

`ps axo time,vsz,rss,pid,command  --no-header | tr -s ' ''_' | sort` show this output:

```
00:00:00 0 0 1021 [nfsiod]
00:00:00 0 0 1052 [lockd]
```

I want to calculate and print together with the ps output in a new column, the relation between `rss`( Real memory usage ) and `vsz`(virtual memory usage of the entire process), for that, I did:

```
for i in   $(ps axo time,vsz,rss,pid,command  --no-header | tr -s ' ''_' | sort)
        do
              var1=$(echo $i | cut -d" " -f2)
              var2=$(echo $i | cut -d" " -f3)
              result=$(echo "$var2 / $var1"  | bc -l)

              echo $i $result
        done
```

However, I get some errors that I do not understand , such as:

```
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: :
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: :
00:00:00
Runtime error (func=(main), adr=3): Divide by zero
0
```

probably referring to these lines

```
                  var1=$(echo $i | cut -d" " -f2)
                  var2=$(echo $i | cut -d" " -f3)
                  result=$(echo "$var2 / $var1"  | bc -l)
```

I appreciate your help, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good morning, this is related to your usage of the for loop.  For splits on every word separated by spaces.  For looping on lines, better use while, like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

ps axo time,vsz,rss,pid,command  --no-header | tr -s ' ''_' | sort | while read line
do
    echo $line
    var1=$(echo $line | cut -d" " -f2)
    var2=$(echo $line | cut -d" " -f3)
    if [ $var1 -ne 0 ]
    then
        result=$(echo "$var2 / $var1"  | bc -l)
    else
        result="N/A"
    fi

    echo $line $result
done
```

I also added a verification for $var1 == 0.  Dividing by 0 is always a problem!

Answer (score 0):

Short solution with `AWK` expression:

```
ps axo time,vsz,rss,pid,command --no-headers --sort=time | awk '{ $(NF+1)=($2==0? 0 : $3/$2) }1'
```

---

- `$(NF+1)` - points to the field added next to last